# Does the Type cover 2 work with the Surface RT?

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-surface, windows-rt

I know that the type cover 2 came out for the Surface 2 and Surface Pro 2, but is it backwards compatible with the Surface RT?

I intend to get the type cover 2 over the original because of the backlit keys and over improvements that I have read about, but I am unsure if the Type cover 2 will work with Surface RT.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Compatability
>
> Surface, Surface 2, Surface Pro, and Surface Pro 2

[Source](http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msusa/en_US/pdp/Type-Cover-2/productID.286867100)

Based on the products specification the answer to your question is: **Yes**